# Retrieve phone number from call log android

Tags: android

I want to  retrieve the number available in the call log in android application.

I do not want to get all the call log and populate in my app activity. Instead I want to use existing android Intent to view and once selected the number from the list, I want the number back in my activity.

I guess I will have to use **startActivityForResult** for this. But what I am confused is what will be the code in this method. I want only the number.

Any help will be appreciated.

Regards,
Shankar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, first from activity A you should create intent

```
Intent i=new Intent(...);
startActivityForResult(i,0)
```

and on the activity B you do this

```
Intent i1=getIntent();
//here you put data
i.putExtra("key","value");
```

and than in the first activity, activity A you get your data like this
in the method:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    String dataINeeded=data.getExtra("key");
}
```

that's it

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] strFields = {
    android.provider.CallLog.Calls.NUMBER, 
    android.provider.CallLog.Calls.TYPE,
    android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME,
    android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NUMBER_TYPE
};
String strOrder = android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC"; 

Cursor mCallCursor = getContentResolver().query(
    android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,
    strFields,
    null,
    null,
    strOrder
    );

if(mCallCursor.moveToFirst()){
    // loop through cursor 
    do{
        int ind=mCallCursor.getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
        int ind1=mCallCursor.getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME);
        Log.v("asd", "NUmber:"+mCallCursor.getString(ind)+"  Name:"+mCallCursor.getString(ind1));
    } while (mCallCursor.moveToNext());
}
```

You can get any info you need , this is just the way to do it

Comment: Thanks . But I am looking for something which will return the only selected number from the android existing call log activity. In your approach this will list all the  logs available in the phone.